# Is it possible to modify only one property of a ndb datastore entity?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have a datastore entity with several properties. Each property is updated using a separate method. However, every so often I find that either a method overwrites a property it is not modifying with an old value (Null).

For example.

```
class SomeModel(ndb.Model): 
  property1 = ndb.StringProperty()
  property2 = ndb.StringProperty()

def method1(self, entity_key_urlsafe):
  data1 = ndb.Key(urlsafe = entity_key_urlsafe).get()
  data1.property1 = "1"
  data1.put()
```

The data 1 entity now has property1 with value of "1"

```
def method2(self, entity_key_urlsafe):
  data1 = ndb.Key(urlsafe = entity_key_urlsafe).get()
  data1.property2 = "2"
  data1.put()
```

The data 1 entity now has property2 with value of "2"

However, if these methods are run to closely in succession - method2 seems to overwrite property1 with its initial value (Null).

To get around this issue, I've been using the deferred library, however it's not reliable (deferred entities seem to disappear every now-and-then) or predictable (the _countdown time seems to be for guidance at best) enough.

My question is: Is there a way to only retrieve and modify one property of a datastore entity without overwriting the rest when you call data1.put()? I.e. In the case of method2 - could I only write to property2 without overwriting property1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to prevent such overwrites, is to make sure your updates are done inside transactions. With NDB this is really easy - just attach the `@ndb.transactional` decorator to your methods:

```
@ndb.transactional
def method1(self, entity_key_urlsafe):
  data1 = ndb.Key(urlsafe = entity_key_urlsafe).get()
  data1.property1 = "1"
  data1.put()
```

The documentation on [transactions](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/transactions) with NDB doesn't give as much background as the (older) [DB version](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/transactions), so to familiarise yourself fully with the limitations and options, you should read both.

Answer (score 2):

I say **No**

I have never seen a reference to that or a trick or a hack. 
I also think that it would be quite difficult for such an operation to exist. 
When you perform `.put()` on an entity the entity is serialised and then written.

An entity is an instance of the Class that you can save or retrieve from the Datastore. 
Imagine if you had a date property that has [auto_now](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties?hl=nl#Date_and_Time)? What would have to happen then? Which of the 2 saves should edit that property?

Though your problem seems to be different. One of your functions commits first and nullifies the other methods value because it retrieves an outdated copy, and not the expected one.

**@Greg's** Answer talks about transactions. You might want to take a look at them.

Transactions are used for concurrent requests and not that much for succession.
Imagine that 2 users pressing the save button to increase a counter at the same time. There transactions work.

```
@ndb.transactional
def increase_counter(entity_key_urlsafe):
    entity = ndb.Key(urlsafe = entity_key_urlsafe).get()
    entity.counter += 1
    entity.put()
```

Transactions will ensure that the counter is correct.
The first that tries to commit the above transaction will succeed and the later will have to retry if retries are on (3 by default).

Though **succession** is something different. Said that, I and @Greg advise you to change your logic towards using transaction if the problem you want to solve is something like the counter example.